# Displaying the result of a JS calculation in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, display

New to JavaScript. I'm trying to create an extremely basic mortgage calculator as my first small JavaScript project. The idea is to display the monthly cost of a mortgage payment.

I'm not getting any errors at the moment. The console.log is showing the correct answer, but I want it to be displayed in the box next to the submit button. I cannot find a way to display the result of the calculation **in that box**. I've scoured the internet and I'm racking my brains over how to do it.
Any help is very much appreciated.

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<form action="">
  <input type="number" id="amountBorrowed" placeholder="Amount Borrowed">
  <input type="number" id="mortgageTerm" placeholder="Term in Years">
  <input type="button" id="sub" value="Submit" onclick="mortgageCalc()">
  <input type="number" id="monthlyCost" name="monthlyCost">  
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function mortgageCalc() {
  var amountBorrowed;
  var mortgageTerm;
  var monthlyCost;
  amountBorrowed = document.getElementById("amountBorrowed").value;
  mortgageTerm = document.getElementById("mortgageTerm").value;
  mortgageTerm *= 12;      
  monthlyCost = (amountBorrowed / mortgageTerm);
   console.log(monthlyCost);
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `document.getElementById("monthlyCost").value = monthlyCost;` — you might want to work on your internet scouring techniques.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need use input for result. If you use input for result - user can edit that field

```js
function mortgageCalc() {
  var amountBorrowed;
  var mortgageTerm;
  var monthlyCost;
  var result = document.getElementById('monthlyCost')
  amountBorrowed = document.getElementById("amountBorrowed").value;
  mortgageTerm = document.getElementById("mortgageTerm").value;
  mortgageTerm *= 12;      
  monthlyCost = (amountBorrowed / mortgageTerm);
   console.log(monthlyCost);
   result.innerHTML = monthlyCost
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="number" id="amountBorrowed" placeholder="Amount Borrowed">
  <input type="number" id="mortgageTerm" placeholder="Term in Years">
  <input type="button" id="sub" value="Submit" onclick="mortgageCalc()">
  <!--<input type="number" id="monthlyCost" name="monthlyCost"> you don't need it-->
  <div>
    <p>Result: </p><p id="monthlyCost"> </p><!-- result will be here -->
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was bored and played around with another version using the an [annuity formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annuity) to calculate a monthly rate if interest has to be considered too:

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('input',ev=>{
  if (ev.target.tagName==="INPUT"){
    const [amnt,yrs,intr]="amountBorrowed,mortgageTerm,yearlyinterest".split(',')
      .map(id=> +document.getElementById(id).value );
    let a,n=yrs*12;                       // number of months
    if(intr>0){
      let q=(1.+intr/100)**(1/12);        // monthly interest rate + 1
      a=amnt * q**n * (q-1)/(q**n-1);.    // annuity formula
    } else { a = amnt/n; }
    document.getElementById('monthlyCost').textContent=a.toFixed(2)
  }
})
```

```css
input {width:150px}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="number" id="amountBorrowed" placeholder="Amount Borrowed">
  <input type="number" id="mortgageTerm" placeholder="Term in Years">
  <input type="number" id="yearlyinterest" placeholder="Yearly interest rate %">  

<div>
    <p>Result: </p><p id="monthlyCost"> </p>
  </div>
</form>
```